# Cufon.refresh unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, cufon

Here's my problem. I have the following code (I took away irrelevant parts):

```
    $('.poll').click(function (e) {
         $.post('/my/ajax/script', {}, function(d) {
             j = $.parseJSON(d);
             var el = $('#my_msg').find('.message-text').find('p'); 
             // That p has class which was consumed by Cufon at document ready
             el.html(j.message);
             $('#my_div').fadeIn(fadeTime, function() { Cufon.refresh(); });                      
         });
     }
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

If I remove `Cufon.refresh` callback, everything works as expected (popup containing `j.message` shows up). But if I leave it, text is rendered only partially (last word is missing, whole text is invisible).

What might be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Can you show us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and it was quite simple. There are two Cufon-prepared fonts loaded at head section of my page, used for different (not intersecting) selectors. After the line about first (desired) font, `Cufon.replace` is called. As there are no other fonts, Cufon replaces everything given with this font. But after that comes the second font.

In that case `Cufon.refresh()` strangely replaces every selector it consumed before with the last font. That happens because first `Cufon.replace(...)` lines didn't specify font.

`Cufon.replace(selector, fontOptions)` instead of `Cufon.refresh()` solved it.